# Connect WSO2 BAM to external Cassandra 1.2.x

Tags: cassandra, wso2, wso2-bam

Is it possible to connect to external instance of the Apache Cassandra (latest version)?

There have been some performance improvements in the version 1.2 that should help with my issue.
The startup time of our Cassandra database instance is more than 10 minutes (size is 50GB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to connect to an external Cassandra cluster. Follow [1]

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM230/Fully-Distributed%2C+High-Availability+BAM+Setup